# Wordpress Custom Webservices

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, api

I have to create Web services From WordPress Database.I have to create web-services for mobile devices like user Posts ,Create and Update  User Profile ,Login ,Login with social Networks ,Account Details ,Messages etc.In this WordPress tables and Custom tables created by plugins or Admin in WordPress will be affected.

I want to Know any WordPress API  or web services Plugin is there are not which can interact with WordPress Tables and Custom tables created by plugins or Admin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.slimframework.com/

Answer (score 9):

We actually did something quite like this.

To start the whole wordpress-api from a custom file you have to do this:

```
<?php require('/wp-load.php'); ?>
```

After that is done you can now use all functions in the Wordpress Api.

For example:

```
<?php 
function getBlogTitle(){
    $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name');
    echo '{restfulapi:{title: '.$blog_title.'}}';
}
?>
```

Is just a small example on what you can do. But it gives you the full power of wordpress and its installed plugins.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Url:

http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/restful-web-services-in-wordpress-plugin/

Full specification is there how to create webservices from WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Wordpress JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

[Full specification](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)